# Mix transactional replication and log shipping?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, database-replication, log-shipping

I've replicated a large database (close to 1TB) to three remote servers using pushing transactional replication. The subscribers are read-only. A lot of data is inserted and updated (from other sources) in one day every month. It always fail the replication after the day and we manually initialize the replication from backup every month.

Is it possible to switch to log shipping before the inserting day and switch back to transactional replication after the bulk insertions are log shipped? So there is no need to copy the big backup file for re-initialization?

Answer (score 1):

No. Transactional replication is logical while log shipping is physical. You can't switch at will between the two. But if your subscribers are read only to start with then transactional replication can be replaced out of the box with log shipping, at the cost of a slight delay in updates and having to disconnect readers on the stand-by sites every time a log is being applied (usually this is nowhere near as bad as it sounds). Given how much more efficient and less problematic log shipping is compared to transactional replication, I would not hesitate for a single second in doing this replace for good.

Answer (score 0):

I question your need to re-initialize on a scheduled basis.  I've had replication topologies go for a really long time without having the need to re-init.  And when we did, it was only because there was a schema change that didn't play nice.  When you say that the large amount of data fails replication, what does that mean?  Replication will gladly deliver large data changes that to the subscribers.  If you're running afoul of latency limits, you can either increase those or break down large transactions into smaller ones at the publisher.  You also have the option of setting the MaxCmdsInTran option for the log reader agent to have *it* break up your transactions for you.